# How to add retrofit basic auth to network module with dagger hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I am new at Kotlin, and I am using dagger hilt for clean code.

I need to basic auth in my all request except the login request because token comes from. login request.

My question is how can I do all my request except login use basic auth with dagger hilt ?

**My module object like this :**

Any advice or sample code please :)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object NetworkingModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesBaseUrl(): String {
        return NetworkingConstants.BASE_URL
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()

        okHttpClient.callTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        okHttpClient.build()
        return okHttpClient.build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideConverterFactory(): Converter.Factory {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitClient(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, baseUrl: String, converterFactory: Converter.Factory): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRestApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

I think I should use BasicAuthInterceptor but how can I add this to hilt module ?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add another interceptor for some other requests, that means **you need to provide different implementations (multiple bindings) of the same type**

**To tell Hilt how to provide different implementations (multiple bindings) of the same type, you can use qualifiers.**

> A qualifier is an annotation used to identify a binding.
> If you need to add another interceptor by implementing Intercepor interface, you can use the @Binds annotation on a function inside a Hilt module.
> **But...**
> you need to create another module for using @Binds.

> Hilt Modules cannot contain both non-static and abstract binding
> methods, so you cannot place @Binds and @Provides annotations in the
> same class.

So your code should be something like this:

//FIRST: define four qualifiers in the NetworkingModule for two types of OkHttpClient and two different retrofitClients:

```
        @Module
        @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
        object NetworkingModule {
            //FIRST: define four qualifiers in the NetworkingMoule
            @Qualifier  // define qualifier for LoginRetrofitClient
            @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
            annotation class LoginRetrofitClient
    
            @Qualifier // define qualifier for OtherRetrofitClient
            @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
            annotation class OtherRetrofitClient
    
            @Qualifier  // define qualifier for LoginOkHttpClient
            @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
            annotation class LoginOkHttpClient
    
            @Qualifier // define qualifier for OtherOkHttpClient
            @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
            annotation class OtherOkHttpClient
    
    
            @Provides
            fun providesBaseUrl(): String {
            return NetworkingConstants.BASE_URL
            }
    
            // make sure add qualifier for LoginRetrofitClient
            @LoggingInterceptor
            @Provides
            fun providesLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
            return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            }
    
            // add @LoginOkHttpClient for providerOkHttpClient which we add AuthBasicInterceptorto to
            @LoginOkHttpClient
            @Provides
            fun provideOkHttpClient(authBasicInterceptor: AuthBasicInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    
            okHttpClient.callTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.addInterceptor(authBasicInterceptor)
            okHttpClient.build()
            return okHttpClient.build()
            }
    
            // add @OtherOkHttpClient for providerOkHttpClient which we add loggingInterceptor to
            @OtherOkHttpClient
            @Provides
            fun provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    
            okHttpClient.callTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            okHttpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            okHttpClient.build()
            return okHttpClient.build()
            }
    
            @Provides
            fun provideConverterFactory(): Converter.Factory {
            return GsonConverterFactory.create()
            }
    
            // make sure add qualifier for LoginRetrofitClient
            @LoginRetrofitClient
            @Provides
            fun provideRetrofitClient(@LoginOkHttpClient okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,  // Remember to add @LoginOkHttpClient qualifier to distinguish OkHttpClient dependencies
            baseUrl: String, converterFactory: Converter.Factory): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .build()
            }
    
    
            @OtherRetrofitClient
            @Provides
            fun provideRetrofitClient(@OtherOkHttpClient okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, // Remember to add @OtherOkHttpClient qualifier to distinguish OkHttpClient dependencies
            baseUrl: String,
            converterFactory: Converter.Factory): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .build()
            }
    
           // also you need different flavors of ApiService by defining two more qualifiers for different retrofitClients which I commented that for simplicity
           // @Provides
            //fun provideRestApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
           // return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
           // }
    
    
            }
```

Now we need to add AuthBasicInterceptor, which we need to create a new module named AuthInterceptorModule.kt and add an
abstract bindAuthInterceptor function of the type Interceptor to it.

AuthInterceptorModule.kt

```
    
    @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
      @Module
      abstract class AuthInterceptorModule {
    
            @Binds
            abstract fun bindAuthInterceptor(basicAuthInterceptor: AuthBasicInterceptor): Interceptor
            }
```

and Create another class named AuthBasicInterceptor.kt implements Interceptor:

```
            class AuthBasicInterceptor @Inject constructor() : Interceptor {
            ...
            }
```

That's it, everything is set. Now you can Inject retrofitClients into other classes like:

```
        @AndroidEntryPoint
        class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        @LoginRetrofitClient
        @Inject lateinit var loginRetrofit: Retrofit

        @OtherRetrofitClient
        @Inject lateinit var otherRetrofit: Retrofit

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       ...
        }

        ...
        }
```